# Devise invalid email or password with valid information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here is the setup:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rails-4.1.1
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mongoid-f9e6fdb1a67c
```

I'm facing an awful error with Devise which never accepts signing a user in except after confirmation.

I use default devise views for sign in / sign up. I overrode two controllers:
confirmation, to allow setting up a password from confirmable email as explained [in Devise's FAQ](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation) and it works like a charm.

I also overrode registration controller to configure permitted parameters for strong parameters as explained [in Devise FAQ](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/v3.0.0.rc#strong-parameters) and this also works like a charm.

Here are my routes:

```
  as :user do
    patch '/users/confirmation' => 'confirmations#update', :via => :patch, :as => :update_user_confirmation
  end
  devise_for :users, controllers: { :confirmations => 'confirmations', :registrations => 'registrations' }
```

Here is my `User` resource:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  #required fields
end
```

So, when creating a user, confirmation mail is sent, confirmation page shows up, user can set his password (which is indeed written in database (checked from console)) and is then signed in and redirected properly.

Now, if I log the user out and try to log in, I always face the error `Invalid email or password` and get redirected back to sign_in page.

I tried tracking where the problem was and all I could find was that lines beyond
`self.password = auth_values[:password]` of `authenticatable#with_authentication_hash` strategy were never hit (even though `auth_values[:password]` is carrying the right password).

I have no idea what can go wrong with that line. Any clue is more than welcome.

========================= EDITED =========================

Here is the registraction controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  #https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/v3.0.0.rc#strong-parameters
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  layout 'public'

  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up){ |params| params.permit(:first_name, :email) }
  end

end
```

Comment: My issue was solved when I restarted the server after running the migrations. For some reason, the server cached something and would not accept the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

why did you override registration controller? you can configure permitted parameter in application controller itself(as the explained in the doc which you have pointed at). I have done it and it works just fine. i would suggest that you should remove route to controller registration and use application controller to permit extra params.

Comment: I just want to keep things clean. I already have way too much stuffs in my ApplicationController. In any case, thee registration controller works perfectly since all allowed strong parameters get assigned in database.

Comment: May be you should put up your code of registration controller.

Comment: OK, I added the code for the registration controller.

Comment: I also tried to add :password to the whitelist of attributes for `sign_in` without any success: `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:password) }` in a prepend_filter of ApplicationController

Comment: you need to sanitize all the params coming from sign up page, for ex: `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up){ |params| params.permit(:first_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }` how come your are not getting any validation error if you aren't passing password!

Comment: Well because my signing up doesn't use password. As I wrote, user define their password in the confirmation controller. After they get their mail, so hence sign_up has no password / password_confirmation.

Comment: in that case your registration controller is fine so are your routes. that leaves confirmation controller!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer, someone on my team brutally commited a change to the SessionsController#new.html.erb view.

Instead of

```
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>
```

code was

```
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :name => 'email' %></div>
```

which caused the email field to be dropped out of the user hash. As it seems that nobody requires(:email), Devise was complaining in fact because email was missing.

Thank you BallsOfSteel for your input, you put me on the track dude!